# How to prevent my mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb, virus

Today I found that all of my test data was removed and when I checked `mongodb` databases there was a `warning` database with the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d55675698589c2384949c7"),
    "BitCoin" : "1Jqw2tHBkUAGY32YzettJiDAwe8A9mUzok",
    "eMail" : "cru3lty@safe-mail.net",
    "Exchange" : "https://localbitcoins.com",
    "Solution" : "Your DataBase is downloaded and backed up on our secured servers. To recover your lost data: Send 0.2 BTC to our BitCoin Address and Contact us by eMail with your MongoDB server IP Address and a Proof of Payment. Any eMail without your MongoDB server IP Address and a Proof of Payment together will be ignored. You are welcome!"
}
```

What can be done to prevent this happening again in the future?

Comment: This is ransomware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message or messages similar to that typically means that you have a database that is open to the internet without authorization (username/password) enabled. **This is not a virus**, this is the result of poor security practices.

Unfortunately there is not much you can do except for restoring from a known good backup at this point. This is likely not an answer you're hoping for, but this is what happened.

To prevent this situation from happening again, **SECURE YOUR SERVERS**. MongoDB provides extensive security features: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/

To ensure your server's security, you can use the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) as a guide.